# Why does my pine script backtest say "No data"

Tags: pine-script

I am writing a simple strategy dedicated to a simple buy-sell strategy with SMIO. However when I try to backtest it just says "No data"

```
    //@version=4
strategy(shorttitle= "MFM", title= "blob", overlay=true)
longlen = input(35, minval=1, title="Long Length")
shortlen = input(15, minval=1, title="Short Length")
siglen = input(15, minval=1, title="Signal Line Length")
erg = tsi(close, shortlen, longlen)
sig = ema(erg, siglen)
osc = erg - sig
plot(osc, color=#FF8080, style=plot.style_histogram, title="SMI Ergodic Oscillator")

long = crossover(close, 0)
short = crossunder(close, 0)

strategy.entry("long", true, when = long)
strategy.entry("short", false, when = short)

strategy.close("long", when = short)
strategy.close("short", when = long)

start = timestamp(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0)
end = timestamp(2021, 6, 1 ,0, 0)
```

Comment: Because the `long` and `short` conditions are always false, the `close` never crosses the value `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The "Close" in your script is giving you the closing price of the ticker. So unless it goes below zero (i.e they're paying people to take it!), you'll never see your long or short conditions. Assuming you want the crossover for your oscillator to give you true values, this should work.

Also, you might want to have your long and short signals default to false by setting them in the parent scope, just for the sake of stability.

```
//@version=4

strategy(shorttitle= "MFM", title= "blob", overlay=true)
longlen = input(35, minval=1, title="Long Length")
shortlen = input(15, minval=1, title="Short Length")
siglen = input(15, minval=1, title="Signal Line Length")
erg = tsi(close, shortlen, longlen)
sig = ema(erg, siglen)
osc = erg - sig
plot(osc, color=#FF8080, style=plot.style_histogram, title="SMI Ergodic Oscillator")

long = false
short = false
if crossover(osc, 0)
    long := true
    label.new(bar_index,close,text="long",style=label.style_label_down)
if crossunder(osc, 0)
    short := true
    label.new(bar_index,close,text="short",style=label.style_label_up)


if long == true
    strategy.entry("my long", true)
if short == true
    strategy.entry("my short", false)

if short == true
    strategy.close("my long")
if long == true
    strategy.close("my short")

start = timestamp(2020, 6, 1, 0, 0)
end = timestamp(2021, 6, 1 ,0, 0)
```